# How to set server side auto responder that sends to fixed email address

Tags: email, exchange-2003, outlook-2003

I have a requirement to send a notification to an external email address whenever a message that meets certain criteria appears in a users mailbox.  This is similar to sending an auto-reply, but always sending a specific message (*not forwarding the original message*) to the external email address, not the sender.

I can't quite figure out how to do this in Exchange 2003/Outlook 2003.  It has to be a server side rule that does not require the Exchange mailbox user is logged in.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, in order for this to be a server side rule, you'll have to create a custom form and publish it to the Exchange Organizational forms library, then set up the rule in Outlook to respond to the messages that meet the criteria with the custom form that you published to the Exchange Organizational forms library. The following links may be helpful:

http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=34

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=244591